# Enum ValueOf null check & exception handling

Tags: java, enums

I am trying to optimize the below piece of code, I wanted to see if there is a way to avoid throwing the exception twice and optimize it to throw just once. any recommendations?

User is an Enum and if no value is found the valueOf method will throw an IllegalArgumentException, while I also have to do a null check here and thus another check for isBlank.

```
private UserContext getContext(String name) {

        UserContext context = null;

        if (StringUtils.isBlank(name)) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("name cannot be Null or empty");
        }

        try {
        context  = map.get(User.valueOf(name.toUpperCase()));

        }catch(IllegalArgumentException e) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("name is not in the list of given names" +name);
        }

        return context;

    }
```

Comment: why the -ve score ?

Comment: I guess that you could set some flag instead of issuing _throws_ in those two places, and then _throw_ from one place in the end of the function if that flag was set. I think that it would be worse in every way compared to your current code (harder to follow the logic, less idiomatic, probably more error prone). (Also, the code will not 'throw twice', if you end up in the first if-body, the code will abort and not reach the second one.) Failing early like that is generally a good idea. Bonus: Your code is potentially vulnerable to 'Reflected XSS attacks', can you spot that error and fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It may be better to move the logic of validating the name for `User` enum into a static method inside the `User` enum.

Also, a check for null/empty seems to be redundant and may be removed completely.

```java
public enum User {
    // ... existing code

    public static User byName(String name) {
        // this check may be removed completely
        if (StringUtils.isBlank(name)) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("name cannot be null or empty");
        }

        return Arrays.stream(User.values())
            .filter(v -> v.name().equalsIgnoreCase(name)) // null-safe case insensitive check
            .findFirst() // Optional<User>
            .orElseThrow(() -> new IllegalArgumentException("name is not in the list of given names: " + name));
    }
}
```

Then method `getContext` may be refactored to be as simple as:

```java
private UserContext getContext(String name) {
    return map.get(User.byName(name));
}
```